# Tracking Separate iPhone and iPad apps using Git

Tags: iphone, git, ipad

I'm hoping that someone has some workflow tips on tracking separate but very (90%) similar iphone and iPad projects using Git.

We are porting our iPad app to iPhone and are looking for a strategy that will allow us to keep most bug fixes and new features synced between the two builds, while allowing us to also keep the .nib and certain classes separate in both branches. I'm very comfortable with Git, but don't have any experience maintaining more than one "master" branch.

My initial thought is to track 3 branches master, iphone and ipad.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the option of creating a universal build or just separate targets in the same project. That way they share the same code base and you do not worry about having to split up the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make one project with two different targets in XCode.  Couldn't be easier.

Something to consider, as a business strategy it is far easier handling one universal app (the same app works on Pad and Fone, as different as you wish on each - but there is only one app for sale).